# The margins change from page to page

Tags: margins

Im currently writing a thesis, for which I was given a template. The strange thing is, that after using `\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}` to see how my format was going, I noticed, that there is some kind of an indent once one the left and once on the right side, changing at each page throughout my document (!Independent of Content!). How can I fix this, or might it even be intentional? It looks wired to me though.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think, that the reason is the documentclass: `\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,bibtotoc,idxtotoc,headsepline,footsepline,footexclude,BCOR12mm,DIV13]{scrbook}`, so considering that it is a "book", it makes sense.

Comment: The reason is not that it is a book, but that  it is typed with the twoside option by default – the margins must correspond on each side of the sheet.